# How To Make Antd Select Dropdown Anchor To Right Of Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I use Ant-Design and in a component I have a `Select` which is placed to the right of the screen. Some of the labels are very long, and therefore when the dropdown appears, it overflows and a scrollbar appears.
I would like to have the dropdown anchor to the right-hand side of the `Select` button rather than to the left-hand side, thus keeping the label length but avoiding the overflow without hiding anything, but Antd doesn't expose an API for doing this and I can't figure out which CSS property to mess with...
An example Sandbox [is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-feather-j0mx2?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not described in the documentation, but since version `4.17.0` the `Select` supports the `placement` property.

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("short");

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        position: "relative"
      }}
    >
      <Select
        value={value}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: "20px"
        }}
        dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
        onChange={(v) => setValue(v)}
        placement={"bottomRight"}
      >
        <Select.Option value="short">Short</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value="long">
          Really Long Label That Makes Everything Weird
        </Select.Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Link to [changelog](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/CHANGELOG.en-US.md#4170)